# React Outputting Empty Node After Iterating Through Subcomponent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a simple react component/sub-component structure. On the subcomponent, I'm trying to loop through an array of objects and output a property value on that object.

There is always a single empty text node displayed at the top of the list I'm outputting and I can't figure out why it's there or how to make it go away.
[A view from React's Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JOEY.png)

Here's my Code:

```html
'use strict'
var React = require('react'),
ReactDOM = require('react-dom')

var UpcomingMovieList = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
  return(<UpcomingMovie movies={this.props}/>)
 }
})

var UpcomingMovie = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
  console.log(this)
  var movie = this.props.movies.movies.map(function(element, index) {
   // console.log(element)
   return(<div className='movie' key={element.id}><div className='movie-content'>{element.title}</div></div>)
  })
  return(<div>UpcomingMovie.{movie}</div>)
 }
})

ReactDOM.render(<UpcomingMovieList movies={window.data.movies}/>,
 document.getElementById('app-container')
)
```

window.data.movies is just an array of objects. I'm just trying to output the title for the moment.

Comment: You have put it there at `<div>UpcomingMovie.{movie}</div>` haven't you? It's not clear what surprises you after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var UpcomingMovie = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>Upcoming Movies</h2>
            {this.props.movies.movies.map(function(element, index) {
               // console.log(element)
              return(<div className='movie' key={element.id}><div className='movie-content'>{element.title}</div></div>)
            })}
          </div>
       );
    }
});
```

It would be more ideal to do the iteration from the `UpcomingMovieList` component though:

```
var UpcomingMovieList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return this.props.movies.map((movie) => {
      return <UpcomingMovie movie={movie} />
    });
  }
});

var UpcomingMovie = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var movie = this.props.movie;
    return (
      <div className='movie' key={movie.id}>
        <div className='movie-content'>{movie.title}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```